# C++ - cURL - Gettings 501 error - Why isn't the server supporting POST

Tags: c++, curl

I am very new to cURL and was modifying the following simple cURL example to work with my needs: 
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

For the simple.cpp:
It works, I have cURL set up correctly and I see the html of www.example.com

For the http-post.cpp

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <curl/curl.h>

    int main(void)
    {
      CURL *curl;
      CURLcode res;

      curl = curl_easy_init();


  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:3000");
    /* Now specify the POST data */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

the following error comes up:

```
<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 501.
<p>Message: Unsupported method ('POST').
<p>Error code explanation: **501 = Server does not support this operation.**
</body>
```

I am using Eclipse to write and test my code, and in the settings I have the following in my settings, so I know I thought I was setup correctly.
[Linker Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wknif.png)

Comment: It has nothing to do with your code. The server simply doesn't support POST requests

Comment: I googled Python simple server to test it out, 
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
which doesn't seem to work with POST? 

I'm completely new to servers and networking, actually I have no background in it, I'm just trying to integrate curl code to my c++ algorithm so please do advice. 

How can I get a local server testing this code? A server that supports POST?

Comment: [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) only supports GET and HEAD requests